# Ширина контролов в процентах в LinearLayout

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, android-linearlayout

Есть разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#303030">
    <TextView
        android:text="Выберите действие"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Кнопка 1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:background="#066da5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Кнопка 2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:background="#bf4680"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Соответственно, кнопки располагаются одна под одной, однако занимают все 100% ширины контейнера. Как можно задать им 80% ширины, не нарушив их вертикального положения?

Я пробовал задать контейнеру `android:orientation="horizontal">`, а кнопкам `android:layout_weight="1"` однако они съезжают куда-то за сам контейнер и их вовсе не видно.

Comment: Нужно точно 80%? Такого параметра нет. Вы можете указать некоторые значения для `layout_marginLeft` и `layout_marginRight` для кнопок. Это добавит отступы по бокам и они не будут растягиваться на всю ширину.

Comment: Margin ведь тоже задается в dp, а значит на разных устройствах будет отображаться по разному

Comment: Как раз таки если задать в dp, то на разных устройствах будет отображаться "практически" одинаково. Но, как я уже сказал, ровно 80% везде таким способом не получить.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#303030">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eighty_percent_layout_holder
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />
     </LinearLayout>
     <!-- ну и т.д. -->
```

То есть каждую кнопку текст помещаете в `LinearLayout`, который занимает всю ширину, а по горизонтали делите место на `0.8` на ваш кнопку/текст, а `0.2` на некий холдер

Answer (score 0):

Проценты можно использовать в `ConstraintLayout`. Ваш случай решается с помощью [Guidlines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html), выставих их на ширине 10% и 90% и привязав края кнопок к ним:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#303030"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Выберите действие"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Кнопка 1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:background="#066da5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Кнопка 2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:background="#bf4680"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Преимущество в том, что с `ConstraintLayout` вы получите только один уровень вложенности элементов View.

P.S. Для использования `ConstraintLayout` необходимо подключить его в `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
```